# The content is loaded into both modals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

There are two modals being used in the Rails app.

1. One modal is used for editing (#editModal)
2. The other one is for displaying text (#textModal)

`link_to` for both the modals are:

```
<%= link_to edit_user_path(user), {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#editModal', 'data-backdrop' => 'static', :class => "icon-edit" } do %> 
    Edit
<% end %> 

<%= link_to display_path(data), {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#textModal', 'data-backdrop' => 'static', :class => "icon-edit" } do %> 
    Display
<% end %>
```

_editModal.html.erb

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= render 'shared/ajax_load' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_textModal.html.erb

```
<div id="textModal" class="modal fade edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body msg-body">
                <%= render 'shared/ajax_load' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when any of the link is clicked one modal is displayed, but `the content is loaded into both the modals`.

Am I doing anything wrong or that's how it works??

Answer (score 0):

Well... Yes and Yes.

You are doing something wrong... and that's how it works. :)

The only difference I can see in your two modals is the `id`. Every other thing is the same... even up to the partial being rendered: `<%= render 'shared/ajax_load' %>`

What this means is that whenever you click any of the buttons, the partial `'shared/ajax_load'` gets populated and will remain populated until you refresh the page.

**Fix:**

Two things I can readily suggest here:

1) You can decide to have separate partials rendered for the two modals

2) You can decide to use `JS` to populate the modal(If you want to use the single partial): then you will have the control to clear off the content of the partial before populating it and rendering into the respective modals

Hope I've been able to explain and hope you understand this.

Comment: Thank you. You mean two different partials for `shared/ajax_load`??

Comment: Yes. that is what I meant by the first option.

Comment: I need to access a div with an id which is within the modal. Am unable to do that because of duplicate ids. Am using div class to access it.

Comment: How do I clear the content of the other modal?? I tried `$("#textModal").html("")`. That didn't help.